# How to update single row of multiple duplicate rows in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
group_id | invoice_amt|insert_date
---------+------------+------
23        1002         10/8/2018
23        1002         10/8/2018
23        1003         11/8/2018
21        1004         12/8/2018
```

When I using following query,

```
select distinct group_id, invoice_amt, insert_date 
from table
```

I'm getting the last 3 rows. But I need all four rows. For that I need to update one of top rows rows by changing date. Group_id and invoice_amt should not change. How to do that.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need all four rows, just remove `DISTINCT`, because it forces unique record set:

```
select group_id, invoice_amt, insert_date from table
```

If you need to change date on all duplicates but one value and have no unique identifier within a table itself you can use internal Oracle pseudocolumn [`ROWID`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm):

```
update table t
set insert_date = < your date here >
where rowid < (
  select max(rowid)
  from table t2
  where t.group_id = t2.group_id
    and t.invoice_amt = t2.invoice_amt
  );
```

Comment: This is not duplicate entry. The entry was made for real as two times. SO I should change date column's time  milli second.
Why `DISTINCT` is must is, sometime real duplicate entries can be made and to avoid them.

Comment: In this case change your `insert_date` column to be type `timestamp with time zone` and your problem is resolved for future. Then perform the `update`. Also, rethink about duplicates - why real duplicates can be made? Then are they really duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
update t
    set insert_date = insert_date + 1
    where rowid > (select min(rowid)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.group_id = t.group_id and t2.invoice_amt = t.invoice_amt
                  );
```